# how to check whether a process was terminated forcefully in c#

Tags: c#, python, winforms

I have a winform application from where i run a python code (the python code run in a console window),this python code creates a few files (basically some reports), now while this code is running if someone closes the console the reports that are generated by the code won't be correct. 
So i want to know is there any way i can prompt user when he clicks the close button of the console and also is there any way to check whether the child process(python code) was exited forcefully in main application so that i can delete the files generated by the code.

Comment: First question: You could simply hide the console, assuming it is opened via your C# code. User could still end it via TM but at least it is "hidden".

Comment: if you can modify python code, I would create dummy file on start and delete it finish, so in case someone terminates python process, dummy file would be there I from that I would know, that process was not finished.

Comment: @andrewb....no i don't want to hide my console, i just want to prompt the user with a msg box if he clicks on the close button.

Comment: @Giedrius....actually i can't change the python code, whatever i have to do i will have to do it in my code....

Comment: @andrewb.....i thought about ur suggestion to hide my console window and i think it can work, can u suggest how could i hide my console window when the user clicks the close button.